# Pausing an Application Procedure

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sleep

I have the following code:

```
MediaPlayer.MoveNext();

 SlideTransition slideTransition = new SlideTransition { Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideRightFadeOut };
 ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(textBlockSong);
 transition.Completed += delegate { transition.Stop(); };
 transition.Begin();

 //would like a pause here.       

 SlideTransition slideTransition2 = new SlideTransition { Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideRightFadeIn };
 ITransition transition2 = slideTransition2.GetTransition(textBlockSong);
 transition2.Completed += delegate { transition2.Stop(); };
 transition2.Begin();
```

However the first transition doesn't get a chance to run as the second part kicks in immediately. So how can I add a pause/delay inbetween the two transitions, which doesn't completely halt the app (like `Thread.Sleep()`) but just waits until the proceeding code is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that familiar yet, but you can try to put your transition into storyboards. Storyboard have a Completed event.

Edit:

What about this?

```
SlideTransition slideTransition = new SlideTransition { Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideRightFadeOut };
ITransition transition = slideTransition.GetTransition(textBlockSong);
transition.Completed += delegate 
{ 
    transition.Stop(); 

    SlideTransition slideTransition2 = new SlideTransition { Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideRightFadeIn };
    ITransition transition2 = slideTransition2.GetTransition(textBlockSong);
    transition2.Completed += delegate { transition2.Stop(); };
    transition2.Begin();

};
transition.Begin();
```

Comment: I can't add the transition into a storyboard I don't think.

Comment: If they are DependencyProperties, you can.

Comment: Could you show me a code sample then, I am not very proficient in c#

Answer (score 0):

Use [Thread.Sleep Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx), it blocks the current thread for the specified number of milliseconds.